# No se puede resolver el simbolo REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: java, android-studio

La idea es escribir en la SD ya tengo los permisos en el manifest pero no se porque me da este error y no se que hacer con el

```
    protected void salvarNotaSD() {
            if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Se necesita acceso de escritura a la SD",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            } else {
                escribirSD();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "La memoria externa no está disponible",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    escribirSD();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No se ha aceptado el permiso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Uso android 7.1.1 el error esta en la linea antes del else REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
Si necesitais algo mas decirlo y lo subo

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos qué es lo que intentas hacer con esto: `new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);`?

Comment: En teoria eso es lo que llama para poder pedir permiso. Si no tengo permiso eso hace que me salte el aviso para darselo. Textualmente el eejrcicio dice
realizaremos la comprobación de si tenemos o
no permiso de escritura en la SD y, en caso de no tenerlo, solicitarlo.

Comment: Pero,  ¿`REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` existe realmente en tu contexto? ¿Es una constante que has definido en algún sitio o que es parte la clase de alguna clase que estás importando a ese contexto? Por otra parte la clase `ActivityCompat` y en consecuencia el método `requestPermissions()` aparece marcado como *deprecated*  (es decir, obsoleto) en la [documentación de Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat#requestpermissions)

Comment: hay es la primera vez que aparece en todo el ejercicio y luego en otro metodo mas abajo.si es obsoleto es el codigo de mi profesor si no se ha actualizado ya no se como es :P

Comment: El error *`Can not find symbol`* suele ocurrir cuando falta importar una clase o algo así, entonces tienes que ver de dónde viene esa constante que te está dando el error, parece que no está en tu contexto.

Comment: no viene de ningun sitio se nombre en ese metodo por primera vez quizas falte algo mi profesor es muy dado a que las practicas esten mal(aunque a el si que le compila) debeser que no nos pasa el codigo corecto a modo de reto o algo

Comment: Pues es que, hasta donde yo sé `REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` no es ni siquiera una constante conocida de Android, como es por ejemplo `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Entonces o esa constante es parte de una clase o algo que el profesor debió ofrecerte o que debe ser definida en el código de algún modo. Según la documentación del método ese valor correspondería el código de la petición.

Comment: Vale te comento el profesor se comio que es un atributo igual a 0 entonces le he puesto al principuo de la clase   private int REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 0; pero aun asi me da un error en otro de los metodos. Edito la preguta con el otro metodo que tiene esa constante me dice constante expresion requerida

Comment: El erro lo da en el case del Swich

Comment: Pero, ¿dónde definiste `REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`? Si lo definiste como miembro de la clase no debería dar error, si lo definiste solamente en uno de los métodos de la misma no estará en otros contextos. Intenta definirla como miembro de la clase, al principio.

Comment: como parte de la clase una vez termina el public class debajo pongo private int  Reques..... Y en el primer metodo no da error pero en el 2º en el swich si

Comment: Si es miembro de la clase no debería dar error. ¿Si lo cambias por `case 0:` qué ocurre?

Comment: Gracias ya no da error pero tengo otro problema voy abrir otra pregunta por no liarla

Comment: Ok, de todos modos, para que la constante te funcione, revisa cómo la estás definiendo. Es extraño que siendo miembro de la clase no la reconozca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error

```
Can not find symbol
```

suele ocurrir cuando falta importar una clase, una constante o algo así.

Entonces tienes que ver de dónde viene la constante `REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` que está dando error. Estuve revisando y no parece ser una constante conocida de Java como `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `LENGTH_SHORT`, `PERMISSION_GRANTED`, etc.

Para solucionar el problema, debes revisar si `REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` existe en alguna otra clase e importarla con algo parecido a esto:

```
import static org.dominio.utils.Constants.REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
```

Asumiendo que tienes una clase `Constants`, dentro de `utils` en tu proyecto.

Si no existe tal clase que guarde las constantes, entonces puedes definirla en la clase actual:

```
//imports


public class TuActivity extends .... {
    private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Código
    }
}
```